# Optimizing slow query in MySql InnoDB Database

Tags: mysql, optimization, innodb, acid

I have a MySql database with a query that is running really slow. I'm trying the best I can to make it perform better but can't see what I'm doing wrong here. Maybe you can?

```
CREATE TABLE `tablea` (
    `a` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `d` mediumint(9) default NULL,
    `c` int(11) default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`a`),
    KEY `d` USING BTREE (`d`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1867710 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tableb` (
    `b` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `d` mediumint(9) default '1',
    `c` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `e` mediumint(9) default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`b`),
    KEY `c` (`c`),
    KEY `d` (`d`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=848150 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The query:

```
SELECT tablea.a, tableb.e
FROM tablea
INNER JOIN tableb ON (tablea.c=tableb.c) AND (tablea.d=tableb.d OR tableb.d=1)
WHERE tablea.d=100
```

This query takes like 10 seconds to run if tablea.d=100 gives 1500 rows and (tablea.d=tableb.d OR tableb.d=1) gives 1600 rows. This seems really slow. I need to make it much faster but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

MySql EXPLAIN outputs:

```
id   select_type table   type   possible_keys key key_len ref       rows  Extra
1    SIMPLE      tablea  ref    d             d   4       const     1092  Using where
1    SIMPLE      tableb  ref    c,d           c   4       tablea.c  1     Using where
```

Comment: See if compound index on c,d will help. Why is the OR tableb.d=1 - imho this hurts performance, try using union instead?

Comment: Post the output of "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%innodb%'". In addition to Darhazer's answer, it looks like InnoDB default config settings are in place.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not confused by the `OR`, the query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT tablea.a, tableb.e
FROM tablea
  INNER JOIN tableb
    ON  tablea.c = tableb.c 
WHERE tablea.d = 100
  AND tableb.d IN (1,100)
```

Try it (using `EXPLAIN`) with various indexes. An index on the `d` field (in both tables) would help. Perhaps more, an index on `(d,c)`.